# I have two passports with two different names, I want to travel to a third country. how should I book my tickets?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel

I have a US passport and a Ukrainian passport. I want to travel to Iran and with my Ukrainian passport I can easily get a visa at arrival. That's not the case with my US passport. However, my last name in my US passport is different from my Ukrainian passport (due to marriage). I want to know how to book my ticket and in what way(s) should I use my passports upon exit and entry. Thank you

Comment: Iran is a different case

Comment: What aspect of traveling to Iran is not answered by the duplicate cited in the comment by @MichaelHampton ?